# Configure conemu with Visual Studio command prompt variables

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, window, conemu

I have searched and searched and got nothing. Please let me know how can I use conemu as a Visual Studio command prompt replacement. I mean how can I add the variable in the `vcvarsall.bat` to a conemu session without actually going to that directory again and again. There has to some kind of shortcut. How can I achieve that. Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not quite sure, what is the problem. If you want to run VC build prompt in ConEmu tab - just set up your Task or Startup Command line to something like this

```
cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

If you want to get shortcut - run something like

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" /cmd cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

Comment: One thing I still don't know how to do is set the start folder by default to `C:` when starting `ConEmu`.

Comment: This depends on how do you start ConEmu (tab actually). You have not tell that.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @maximus's answer I found that I needed to double the quotes to make that work.

```
cmd.exe /k ""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

Also, if you want that to run in administrator mode then you want it to be

```
cmd.exe /k ""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 -new_console:a
```

Comment: The `-new_console:a` does not work on my system

Comment: worked for me by placing in the supplied text in the bottom box, after the Set Prompt portion.  I had to adjust my path for Vs 2012, which is version 11.0